# Mule - Delete files with Files Connector

Tags: file, mule, delete-file, mule-flow

This is my main `mule flow`:

```
HTTP > Payload > File (Create) > Property (File Name) JMS
```

And that JMS calls to `other flow` that starts with JMS

```
JMS > JSON TO XML > File (Delete by file name)
```

Firstly, I create a file with the `JSON` message.

And finally, when `JSON` message is transformed to `XML`, I try to **delete** the file by name **calling a property** that tell me the name.

But the files doesn't delete. Its output this action by log:

```
Writing file to: C:\errors\91fa03a0-dd33-11e5-a0d9-408d5c4c1bf3.dat
```

How can I do to **delete** it?

I tried with the option **autoDelete** in the `Connector Configuration` but it doesn't delete.

```
<file:connector name="File1" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.fileName]" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this file outbound endpoint to delete a file.

If you would use something like S3 for example you can, but those connectors are 'operation-based'.

It's meant to write an new file or append data to an existing one.

The autoDelete option is for deleting the file once it has been read by a file inbound endpoint.

More info:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/file-transport-reference

If you want to delete and for your usecase you should use a piece of JAVA code and use methods from the File Class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html